# Ι want to increase the width for

Tags: tcolorbox

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{exo}[1][]{
  enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=myblue,coltitle=myblue,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
  sharp corners,
  detach title,
  leftrule=18mm,
  underlay unbroken and first={\node[below,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries,align=center]
    at ([xshift=-11mm,yshift=-1mm]interior.north west) {Exercice\\\thetcbcounter};},
  breakable,pad at break=1mm,
  #1,
  code={\ifdefempty{\tcbtitletext}{}{\tcbset{before upper={\tcbtitle\par\medskip}}}},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{exo}[title= Espaces vectoriels calcul de dimension]
Soit $E$ un $\mathbb{K}$-espace vectoriel de dimension finie, $g$ et $h$ deux endomorphismes de E. On pose :$$\mathcal{F}=\lbrace f\in\mathcal{L}(E)  \text{tel que} : h\circ f\circ g = 0\rbrace$$
\begin{enumerate}
\item Vérifier que $\mathcal{F}$ est un sous-espace vectoriel de $\mathcal{L}(E)$.
\item On suppose dans cette question que $h=id_E$. Soit $S$ un supplémentaire de $\ker(g)$ dans $E$.
 \begin{itemize}
  \item Montrer que l'application $\Phi:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{L}(S,E), f\mapsto f_{/S}$ est un isomorphisme d'espaces vectoriels.
  \item En déduire la dimension de $\mathcal{F}$ dans ce cas
\end{itemize}  
\item Calculer la dimension de $\mathcal{F}$ lorsque $g=id_E$ .
\item Calculer $\dim\mathcal{F}$ dans le cas général.
\end{enumerate}
\end{exo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Increase the width for *what*? And what is the  `exo` environment?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Your `exo` environment is as big as it could get naturally. With that, I mean it is stretching all the `\textwidth` available. If you want to extend the width further, you will have warning(s) saying that you are out of the page (and going into the margins). I don't suggest that but I have provided an example permitting you to do so. It also compares what you have and what I have come up with.

**Another suggestion:** decrease the margins and keeping the same code you have.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{exo}[1][]{
  enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=myblue,coltitle=myblue,
  width=\textwidth, % You don't have this, but it doesn't change anything because what you have is the default
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
  sharp corners,
  detach title,
  leftrule=18mm,
  underlay unbroken and first={\node[below,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries,align=center]
    at ([xshift=-11mm,yshift=-1mm]interior.north west) {Exercice\\\thetcbcounter};},
  breakable,pad at break=1mm,
  #1,
  code={\ifdefempty{\tcbtitletext}{}{\tcbset{before upper={\tcbtitle\par\medskip}}}},
}

% Newer tcolorbox environment
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{exoBigger}[1][]{
  enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=myblue,coltitle=myblue,
  width=\textwidth+4em, % Incremented by 2em
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
  sharp corners,
  detach title,
  leftrule=18mm,
  underlay unbroken and first={\node[below,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries,align=center]
    at ([xshift=-11mm,yshift=-1mm]interior.north west) {Exercice\\\thetcbcounter};},
  breakable,pad at break=1mm,
  #1,
  code={\ifdefempty{\tcbtitletext}{}{\tcbset{before upper={\tcbtitle\par\medskip}}}},
}


\begin{document}
\textbf{Original:}
\begin{exo}[title= Espaces vectoriels calcul de dimension]
Soit $E$ un $\mathbb{K}$-espace vectoriel de dimension finie, $g$ et $h$ deux endomorphismes de E. On pose :$$\mathcal{F}=\lbrace f\in\mathcal{L}(E)  \text{tel que} : h\circ f\circ g = 0\rbrace$$
\begin{enumerate}
\item Vérifier que $\mathcal{F}$ est un sous-espace vectoriel de $\mathcal{L}(E)$.
\item On suppose dans cette question que $h=id_E$. Soit $S$ un supplémentaire de $\ker(g)$ dans $E$.
 \begin{itemize}
  \item Montrer que l'application $\Phi:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{L}(S,E), f\mapsto f_{/S}$ est un isomorphisme d'espaces vectoriels.
  \item En déduire la dimension de $\mathcal{F}$ dans ce cas
\end{itemize}  
\item Calculer la dimension de $\mathcal{F}$ lorsque $g=id_E$ .
\item Calculer $\dim\mathcal{F}$ dans le cas général.
\end{enumerate}
\end{exo}

\textbf{Modified:}
\begin{exoBigger}[title= Espaces vectoriels calcul de dimension]
Soit $E$ un $\mathbb{K}$-espace vectoriel de dimension finie, $g$ et $h$ deux endomorphismes de E. On pose :$$\mathcal{F}=\lbrace f\in\mathcal{L}(E)  \text{tel que} : h\circ f\circ g = 0\rbrace$$
\begin{enumerate}
\item Vérifier que $\mathcal{F}$ est un sous-espace vectoriel de $\mathcal{L}(E)$.
\item On suppose dans cette question que $h=id_E$. Soit $S$ un supplémentaire de $\ker(g)$ dans $E$.
 \begin{itemize}
  \item Montrer que l'application $\Phi:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{L}(S,E), f\mapsto f_{/S}$ est un isomorphisme d'espaces vectoriels.
  \item En déduire la dimension de $\mathcal{F}$ dans ce cas
\end{itemize}  
\item Calculer la dimension de $\mathcal{F}$ lorsque $g=id_E$ .
\item Calculer $\dim\mathcal{F}$ dans le cas général.
\end{enumerate}
\end{exoBigger}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to increase the `width` of the `tcolorbox` environment called `exo`. For this purpose, you can usually add the `width` option in the `exo` `tcolorbox`. 
To extend it, for instance:

```
width=1.1\textwidth,
```

or

```
width=\textwidth+2em,
```

With the `leftrule` option you can increase the `width` of the blue box.

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{exo}[1][]{
  center, % added
  width=\textwidth+20em, % added
  enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=myblue,coltitle=myblue,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
  sharp corners,
  detach title,
  leftrule=22mm, % changed
  underlay unbroken and first={\node[below,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries,align=center]
    at ([xshift=-11mm,yshift=-1mm]interior.north west) {Exercice\\\thetcbcounter};},
  breakable,pad at break=1mm,
  #1,
  code={\ifdefempty{\tcbtitletext}{}{\tcbset{before upper={\tcbtitle\par\medskip}}}},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{exo}[title= Espaces vectoriels calcul de dimension]
Soit $E$ un $\mathbb{K}$-espace vectoriel de dimension finie, $g$ et $h$ deux endomorphismes de E. On pose :$$\mathcal{F}=\lbrace f\in\mathcal{L}(E)  \text{tel que} : h\circ f\circ g = 0\rbrace$$
\begin{enumerate}
\item Vérifier que $\mathcal{F}$ est un sous-espace vectoriel de $\mathcal{L}(E)$.
\item On suppose dans cette question que $h=id_E$. Soit $S$ un supplémentaire de $\ker(g)$ dans $E$.
 \begin{itemize}
  \item Montrer que l'application $\Phi:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{L}(S,E), f\mapsto f_{/S}$ est un isomorphisme d'espaces vectoriels.
  \item En déduire la dimension de $\mathcal{F}$ dans ce cas
\end{itemize}  
\item Calculer la dimension de $\mathcal{F}$ lorsque $g=id_E$ .
\item Calculer $\dim\mathcal{F}$ dans le cas général.
\end{enumerate}
\end{exo}
\end{document}
```

## Note:

As [M. Al Jumaily](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497264/89320) said the `exo` box has already the `\textwidth`. Take into consideration the warning and of course his suggestion.

With the package `geometry` you can change the left and right margins, `lmargin` and `rmargin`, respectively:

```
\usepackage[lmargin=.15in]{geometry}
```

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[lmargin=.15in]{geometry} % added
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{exo}[1][]{
  %center, % added
  %width=\textwidth+5em, % added
  enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=myblue,coltitle=myblue,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
  sharp corners,
  detach title,
  leftrule=22mm, % changed
  underlay unbroken and first={\node[below,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries,align=center]
    at ([xshift=-11mm,yshift=-1mm]interior.north west) {Exercice\\\thetcbcounter};},
  breakable,pad at break=1mm,
  #1,
  code={\ifdefempty{\tcbtitletext}{}{\tcbset{before upper={\tcbtitle\par\medskip}}}},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{exo}[title= Espaces vectoriels calcul de dimension]
Soit $E$ un $\mathbb{K}$-espace vectoriel de dimension finie, $g$ et $h$ deux endomorphismes de E. On pose :$$\mathcal{F}=\lbrace f\in\mathcal{L}(E)  \text{tel que} : h\circ f\circ g = 0\rbrace$$
\begin{enumerate}
\item Vérifier que $\mathcal{F}$ est un sous-espace vectoriel de $\mathcal{L}(E)$.
\item On suppose dans cette question que $h=id_E$. Soit $S$ un supplémentaire de $\ker(g)$ dans $E$.
 \begin{itemize}
  \item Montrer que l'application $\Phi:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{L}(S,E), f\mapsto f_{/S}$ est un isomorphisme d'espaces vectoriels.
  \item En déduire la dimension de $\mathcal{F}$ dans ce cas
\end{itemize}  
\item Calculer la dimension de $\mathcal{F}$ lorsque $g=id_E$ .
\item Calculer $\dim\mathcal{F}$ dans le cas général.
\end{enumerate}
\end{exo}
\end{document}
```